# Contract.methods.call() returning a error Web3-js

Tags: javascript, web3js

I am using web3 CDN and I have deployed contract with two variables. example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Sweet() {
    address public owner;
    uint256 sweets;
    uint256 shops;
    constructor(uint256 _sweets, uint256 _shops){
       owner = msg.sender;
       sweets = _sweet;
       shops = _shops;
    }

    function setSweetAndShop(uint256 _sweets, uint256 _shops) public {
       sweets = _sweets;
       shops = _shops;
    }
}
```

After deploying this example code everything works fine in the remix. After that, I have created an example DAPP.

```
async function change(){
var web3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
var account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
var abi = [];
var contract = "0x000000000.........";
var token = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract);
try{
token.methods.setSweetAndShop(10, 20).call({
   from: account[0], 
   gas: 800000
})
.then(function(error, result) {
    if (!error){
            console.log(result);
        }else{
            console.log(error); //  This part is returning an error g{} , no data inside.
        }
    })
}catch(error){
    console.log(error)
}
}
```

Comment: What is the `window.ethereum`? MetaMask?

Comment: yes, metamask wallet

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Your method must return something to be "Callable"

In contrast to `MethodObject.send(options)` which broadcasts transaction to blockchain, the `MethodObject.call(options)` function doesn't run any transactions in the blockchain , it is used to **simulate** EVM method call inside RPC_NODE and get the response of the function, **calling cannot alter the smart contract state**.

Your method in smart-contract makes changes in states and doesn't return anything, as we can assume, by saying simulate it doesn't forbid us to `call` EVM methods that changes states, but in reality it doesn't change the state, but can be used to predetermine some mutations, e.g. in PancakeRouter there is a method `getAmountsOut`, which uses current liquidity state change simulation to predetermine estimated output of swap.

Even logically, calling a method that doesn't make changes and doesn't return anything, is unlogical.

So, you need to add a return statement to have a useful method and avoid errors.